# Prevent UILabel localization

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

XCode automatically generates a `.strings` file for every storyboard, based on the languages you set in your project properties. Those files contain every visual element used in the base storyboard. **Is there any way to prevent a UILabel in the storyboard from being localised and be written in that `.strings` file?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to do this right now. Your best bet is to add a comment to each label using Interface Builder asking translators not to localise it. You should file a bug report requesting this at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)